# Reading multiple lines of input with scanf

Tags: c

Writing a program for class, restricted to only scanf method. Program receives can receive any number of lines as input. Trouble with receiving input of multiple lines with scanf.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    char s[100];
    while(scanf("%[^\n]",s)==1){
        printf("%s",s);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Example input:

```
Here is a line.
Here is another line.
```

This is the current output:

```
Here is a line.
```

I want my output to be identical to my input. Using scanf.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading multiple lines of input with scanf()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13592875/reading-multiple-lines-of-input-with-scanf)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this code and use tab key as delimeter

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    char s[100];
    scanf("%[^\t]",s);
    printf("%s",s);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: can you tell me what is the value you are using as input

Comment: I think that is because of memory problem as C is not a memory safe language.

Comment: When I increased the array size to 1024 it worked perfectly. Can you explain why, and how I can choose the correct array size?

Comment: @PuneetPurohit : And what about if I need a tab limiter but I need read a float instead of a string?

Answer (score 10):

I think what you want is something like this (if you're really limited only to scanf):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    char s[100];
    while(scanf("%[^\n]%*c",s)==1){
        printf("%s\n",s);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The %*c is basically going to suppress the last character of input.

From `man scanf`

```
An optional '*' assignment-suppression character: 
scanf() reads input as directed by the conversion specification, 
but discards the input.  No corresponding pointer argument is 
required, and this specification is not included in the count of  
successful assignments returned by scanf().
```

[ Edit: removed misleading answer as per Chris Dodd's bashing :) ]

Comment: +1 for the correct first answer, -1 for the totally wrong and misleading second answer.  Why to people keep recomming `while(!feof)`? A sure-fire indicator that the programmer doesn't know what they're doing.

Comment: How can I eliminate the extra linebreak (\n) on the last line of output?

Comment: @ChrisDodd, yeah you're correct, I've edited my answer to remove the misleading bit.

Comment: @Michael : Ok, and what would be the regex if I need to read an integer or a float?

Comment: You should probably also add a maximum length to the scanf string specifier to prevent buffer overflows when input is greater than 99 characters: `scanf("%99[^\n]%*c",s)`.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you a hint.

You need to repeat the scanf operation until an "EOF" condition is reached.

The way that's usually done is with the

```
while (!feof(stdin)) {
}
```

construct.

Comment: -1: `while(!feof(..))` is pretty much always wrong and always gets the last line wrong unless you go to heroic efforts to post-process it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this piece of code..
It works as desired on a GCC compiler with C99 standards..

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
int s[100];
printf("Enter multiple line strings\n");
scanf("%[^\r]s",s);
printf("Enterd String is\n");
printf("%s\n",s);
return 0;
}
```