# Getting multiple lines of input with scanf() in c

Tags: c, input, scanf

I am trying to grab multiple lines of input with scanf, all the lines have the same formatting
example line:

1, 05:05:04, 1, 1103

the current code I have grabs only one line

```
scanf(" %d, %d:%d:%d, %d, %d", int1, int2, int3, int4, int5, int6);
```

Comment: please post the failing code, not just that line...

Comment: Add to arrays using the repetition of each line.

Comment: If you want to read *lines*, don't use `scanf`. (Actually, just avoid using `scanf` in general. http://www.c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html )

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading multiple lines of input with scanf()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13592875/reading-multiple-lines-of-input-with-scanf)

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for this?

```
while (scanf("%d,%d:%d:%d,%d,%d",
           &int1, &int2, &int3, &int4, &int5, &int6) == 6) {
    //use int1, int2, int3, int4, int5, int6
}
```

Comment: +1, but I'd completely remove white space from the format string: `"%d,%d:%d:%d,%d,%d"`. The conversion `"%d"` already includes leading whitespace on its own.

Answer (score 0):

This scanfs 2 lines:

```
scanf("%d, %d:%d:%d, %d, %d\n%d, %d:%d:%d, %d, %d", &int1, &int2...)
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try using a for loop. So it would be

`for (int i =0; i < NumberOfLines;i++)
{
   scanf(" %d, %d:%d:%d, %d, %d", int1, int2, int3, int4, int5, int6);
}`